# Docker desktop is failing DNS lookup on both Windows and Mac

Tags: windows, mac, dns, docker, docker-desktop-app

I have three machines on the same network (simple, home one with BT router) Windows, Mac and Linux.  The first two, running Docker Desktop (4.23.0) exhibit this issue, while the Linux one (running native dockerd) doesn't.

DNS lookup is failing from within any container.  This also means I can't build containers and nor can I pull images.  So, e.g., "docker pull ubuntu" gives the following (after 20 seconds):

**Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup http.docker.internal on 192.168.65.7:53: read udp 192.168.0.1:49442->192.168.65.7:53: i/o timeout**

Similarly, building a Dockerfile containing just "FROM ubuntu:20.04" gives:

```
$ docker build -t test .
[+] Building 10.1s (3/3) FINISHED                                           docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from dockerfile                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 55B                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                       0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04                10.0s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04:
------
dockerfile:1
--------------------
   1 | >>> FROM ubuntu:20.04
   2 |
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: ubuntu:20.04: failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/ubuntu/manifests/20.04": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup http.docker.internal on 192.168.65.7:53: read udp 192.168.0.1:47040->192.168.65.7:53: i/o timeout
```

Within an existing (Ubuntu) container (running under WSL2), 'curl google.com' gives:

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: google.com

(This is actually working on the Mac currently, not on Windows though).

I can make the lookup work in the Windows Ubuntu container by adding 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' to /etc/resolv.conf (usually it has 'nameserver 127.0.0.11') but that's not helping my pull/build problem.

Any help or hints on next steps appeciated!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, but to be honest I still don't know the reason or actually the cure.

Mac.  I Reverted back to an earlier version.  Deleted the ~/.docker directory.  Re-installed the latest version.  Was just at the point of removing everything including all the data (e.g. images etc.) and suddenly it worked.

Windows.  Uninstalled.  Deleted ~/.docker (within WSL2).  Reinstalled latest.  Worked.

No idea of the cause but enough removing and re-installing worked.  Two days of my life...